# expanding tensor notation of Navier stokes equation

Tags: tensors

I'm trying to expand the variable density and viscosity Navier-stokes equation for incompressible flows but I've had no luck so far.

The Navier-Stokes in tensor notation is:

$$
\rho \dfrac{Du_i}{Dt} = -\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial x_i} + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(\mu \left( \dfrac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} + \dfrac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} \right) \right)
$$

I'm confused with how to expand the last term in the above equation. The similar term in vector notation is $\nabla.(\mu(\nabla \underline{u}+\nabla\underline{u}^T))$

I've tried to expand the term $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(\mu \left( \dfrac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} + \dfrac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} \right) \right)$ in x direction as :

$$
(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y})(\mu(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}))
$$
$$
= \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(\mu(2\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x})) + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}(\mu(2\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}))
$$

Is this expansion correct?

Thank you

Comment: Is $\mu$ here an arbitrary function?

Comment: yes, $\mu$ is a function of space as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\nabla \cdot [\mu (\nabla \mathbf{u}+\nabla \mathbf{u}^T)]=\nabla \mu \cdot(\nabla \mathbf{u}+\nabla \mathbf{u}^T)+ \mu \nabla^2\mathbf{u} + \mu \nabla(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}).$$

In terms of Cartesian components, the $\mathbf{e}_i$ component is (summing over $j =1,2$ in $2$D or $j =1,2,3$ in $3$D):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left[\mu \left(\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}+\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} \right)\right]=\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial x_j}\left(\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}+\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} \right)+\mu \frac{\partial^2 u_i}{\partial x_j \partial x_j}+\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_j}\right).$$

Note that the Einstein summation convention is used here:

$$\frac{\partial^2 u_i}{\partial x_j \partial x_j}=\sum_{j=1}^3\frac{\partial^2 u_i}{\partial x_j^2}=\frac{\partial^2 u_i}{\partial x_1^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u_i}{\partial x_2^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u_i}{\partial x_3^2}$$

In $2$D with $u = u_1$, $v = u_2$, $x = x_1$ and  $y = x_2$, the x-component is

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left[\mu \left(\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_j}+\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_1} \right)\right]=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(2 \mu  \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[ \mu  \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \right)\right],$$

and the y-component is

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left[\mu \left(\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_j}+\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_2} \right)\right]=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[ \mu  \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \right)\right]+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(2 \mu  \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \right).$$

Comment: It seems that the expansion that you have provided is in non-conservative form..I'd like to keep the $\mu$ in the $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$ term.

Comment: @Pranav -- added it above.

Comment: I tried to implement above expanded form in my code (Navier-Stokes solver using projection method) and I'm testing my code using lid-driven cavity problem. I'm getting the secondary vortex in the left corner instead of right. (see here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4uohySoVqBCYktRR2lDNVY1amc/edit?usp=sharing)

When I see your expansion, I noticed that you have used $\nabla u^T$ but I guess it should be $\nabla^T u$. Is there any difference between the two? Plus can you also highlight how to treat $\nabla^T$ operator?

Comment: Can I expand $\nabla.(\mu(\nabla \underline{u}+\nabla^T\underline{u}))$ as $\nabla.\left(\mu\nabla u\right) + \nabla.\left(\mu\nabla^T u \right)$ and then expand? What would be the result then?

Comment: In the equations of motion the viscous force term is the divergence of the rate-of-strain tensor which must be $\nabla u + \nabla u^T$. $\nabla u$ is a second-order tensor so the transpose has the obvious meaning.  I dont know what you mean by $\nabla^T u$ but it is not applicable for fluid motion.

Comment: As written the components are correct. For constant $\mu$ and incompressible flow it reduces to Laplacian of $u$.

Comment: Oh, then probably there's some bug in my code which I need to find out...

Comment: As you are new to StackExchange - we are told to avoid extended chats. If this answer has helped you then I would be very happy if you accepted. If this is leading you to new questions, you should post again. Thanks

Comment: oh ok, Thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: Thanks. The cavity flow could have vortices in both corners. Maybe not converged

Comment: Thank you @RRL, now I'm getting correct solution. There was a bug in my code. :)
Yes, there are vortices in both the corners. If I increased the Re and grid resolution, I can capture that correctly.

Comment: @Pranav:  Glad to hear that - not easy solving Navier-Stokes with inertial terms